# Server side projection with DateTime property is not deserialized on the client

Tags: javascript, breeze

I have a projection defined on the server (IQuerable - anonymous type). The anonymous type contains DateTime properties, which are not deserialized on the client, but instead remain strings.

How can I easily convert them to JS DateTime objects in the same way as breeze normally does?

I have the default WebApi configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `breeze.DataType.parseDateFromServer(dateString);` - don't know if this is optimal, but it works correctly with the default WebApi configuration.
Moment needs "Z" at the end of the string to parse a date as UTC. Breeze in contrast, treats dates without timezone information as UTC.

Comment: This is a good approach.  With anonymous types Breeze doesn't "know" the datatypes of individual properties, so it just leaves the data alone. Using parseDateFromServer is the correct approach as well because it insures consistency across browsers.  Most dates are serialized by default without timezone information, ( because this data doesn't exist on the datatabe), so the parseDateFromServer method will add the "Z" if an explicit timezone is not found.  This is necessary because different browsers treat UTC dates without timezones differently, but all are consistent if a timezone is specified

Answer (score 1):

If you need to deserialize them manually, then the best library I've found is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

It should be as simple as: `var m = moment("DATE_AS_STRING_HERE");` and you can then [get a native JS date](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) by calling `m.toDate();`

Moment handles [a number of string date formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) out of the box, and I've found it to work well with WebApi.

**Update**:

From the Docs:

```
The following ISO-8601 formats are supported across all browsers.

"YYYY-MM-DD"
"YYYY-MM-DDTHH"
"YYYY-MM-DD HH"
"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm"
"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"
"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS"
"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS"
"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss Z"
"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z"
Note: Automatic cross browser ISO-8601 support was added in version 1.5.0
```

And:

> Moment.js does detect if you are using an ISO-8601 string and will
>   parse that correctly without a format string.

So it appears that yes, it should parse ISO-8601 strings fine (indeed, this is its preferred string format).

Comment: I already use moment.js; I'm just not sure it parses strings the same way as breeze.js (ISO 8601); I should give this a try, because it looks like moment.js "detects if you are using an ISO-8601 string and will parse that correctly without a format string". Thank you!